# TFS / Azure Devops - This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, version-control, acl

I cannot check code into Team Foundation Server source control. Visual Studio shows an error "This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified." It does not specify the path with the problematic ACL.

Answer (score 0):

The access control list for a file or folder needs to be rewritten in canonical form. Because Visual Studio does not specify the path, the easiest way to fix this is to try several until it works. Open an administrator PowerShell prompt. I found that this does not necessarily work unless running as administrator, although no errors indicate that it fails. Powershell will be used to get and set the ACLs of several paths, doing so rewrites them in canonical form without any additional steps.

First try the directory where TFS stores the workspace files:

```
cd $env:localappdata
cd '.\Microsoft\Team Foundation\'
gci -Recurse | % { Get-Acl $_ | Set-Acl $_ } # rewrite ACLs for all child folders and files
$x = gi . # get current folder
Get-Acl $x | Set-Acl -Path $x # rewrite its ACL
```

Now try parent directories (repeat this procedure to recurse up - for me the problem was fixed once I rewrote the ACL for the AppData folder)

```
$x = $x.Parent # get the parent directory
$x # display the folder to the console so you know what path you are working on
Get-Acl $x | Set-Acl -Path $x # rewrite its ACL
```

If this does not work, try repeating these steps for your source control path and its parent directories.